# Does applying a device tree overlay trigger driver probing?

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, fpga, device-driver

Say I have a Linux system running on an SoC (by which I mean an ARM CPU hooked up to an FPGA). If I reprogram the FPGA with a new bitstream, the devices attached to the system have now changed. It's my understanding that this change is signalled to the OS using a device tree overlay.

However, does applying the overlay "do the right thing" with respect to the device model? Here is a short list of things that should happen:

- Old `struct device` entries for the old bitstream should be removed, and `sysfs` updated
- Drivers for the old devices should be stopped
- New `struct device` entries for the new bitstream should be registered, `sysfs` updated
- Somehow, these new `struct device` entries need to be matched up with `struct device_driver` entries (and the `probe()` function should be called)

I tried taking a quick look at the [device tree overlay source code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3-rc8/source/drivers/of/overlay.c#L910) to see if these events occur, but I wasn't really able to understand what's going on.

To recap: does applying a device tree overlay (on a running system) do all the proper changes to the device model and trigger the proper unloading and probing of drivers?

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have figured it out. The `of_overlay_apply` function makes a call to `overlay_notify`. The device tree code (usually prefixed with `of`, which stands for Open Firmware) maintains [a list of callbacks](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3-rc8/source/drivers/of/overlay.c#L122). When you run notification, these callbacks get called.

Different device/bus drivers can register a callback to the global list of notification callback (see [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3-rc8/source/drivers/of/overlay.c#L136)). For example, the i2c driver registers [this function](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3-rc8/source/drivers/i2c/i2c-core-of.c#L234) (via [this function call](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3-rc8/source/drivers/i2c/i2c-core-base.c#L1833) in the `init` function), which appears to do all the necessary driver removing/registering.

So, it appears that it is the driver's job to "subscribe" to device tree overlay notifications, and to perform the appropriate actions.

Comment: Yes and no. If something is done for many of the drivers, pretty much it means it’s a job of frameworks or bus drivers or subsystem librarians to do that.